# A Problem using Total Probability

Tags: probability

A hiker starts by taking one of n available trails, denoted 1,2,...,n.An hour into the hike, trail i subdivides into 1 +i subtrails, only one of which leads to the hiker’s destination.  The hiker has no map and makes random choices of trail and subtrail. What is the probability of reaching the destination?

I define $Ti$= {hiker choosing trail $i$} and $D$= {Hiker chooses right sub trail to reach his destination}.

Using the total probability theorem, $P(D)=P(T1)P(D|T1)+P(T2)P(D|T2)+...+P(Tn)P(D|Tn)$.

Since the hiker chooses his trails randomly, $P(Ti)=1/n$ and $P(D|Ti)=1/(1+i)$

With these probabilities, I would claim that the final answer is $P(D)=\sum_{i=1}^n(1/n)(1/(1+i))$.

I don't think I can evaluate the summation without knowing $n$, so would my expression be a valid solution to the problem?

Comment: Will each initial trail $1,2, \,\, ... \,\, , n$ lead to the hiker's destination given the correct subtrail is chosen?

Comment: That is the assumption that I made.

Answer (score 1):

$$P = \frac{1}{n} \sum\limits_{i=2}^{n-1} \frac{1}{i} = \frac{H_{n-1}-1}{n}$$

where $H_n$ is the [Harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).